# import sass file into all components

Tags: sass, vuejs3

I've created `_varibales.scss` file into assets folder and make `vue.config.js` in root of my project. But it's not working;

_varibales.scss

```
$blue : blue;
$white : black;
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          data: `
                @import  "@/assets/scss/variables";
                `
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

blog-post.vue (It is a component)

```
<style lang="scss">
    h1{
            background: $blue;
            color: $white;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: The path in your import looks wrong. I don't think the sass compiler would know what to do with a path starting like this `@`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use absolute path like:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: @import './src/assets/scss/variables';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not matter which path is used. when I set lang to sass and use variables without import sass file it is not working.

Comment: @imanhosseingholizadeh Have you imported your sass file inside main.js?

Comment: No i don't. Is it necessary ?